# Edits to images shared in Google Photos

Tags: google-photos

Is there any way to force propagation of changes to an image in Google Photos after it has been shared using partner sharing?

I recently uploaded a bunch of photos from a slide scanner. Google Photos did not pick up dates I'd embedded in the filenames, but instead set seeming arbitrary dates starting at Jan. 1, 2000 (possibly from the scanner?)

My wife then pulled some of those images with the bad dates to her Google Photos account, using the 'Save' button. (See screenshot)

I subsequently corrected the dates on my account — but the changes haven’t carried over to the images saved on her account.

Anyone know a way I can make this happen?

[image: Google Photos Save button screenshot]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Photo.SE! Your question does not mention it, but are you using [partner sharing](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/7378858?hl=en)? If so, please [edit] your question to mention that. Also include any research you've done so far, as that is [the first step in asking a good question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). This prevents that people take time to come up with a solution you've tried already and which didn't work.

Comment: Thanks, just edited to reflect that my question does pertain to partner sharing. My attempts at a solution have been as I mentioned in the 4th paragraph in my post: changing the date on the original photo in my account, then checking to see if the changes showed up in my wife's account (they weren't).

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can't  make these changes to populate. These images are not linked objects, they are independent.

Anything you publish in internet is out of your hands and you have zero control over it.